# Which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch support particular versions of Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Based on what I've researched so far, it seems that `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.1.5.RELEASE` only supports Elasticsearch < 5.0.0 (based on the [version support matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix)). Given the fact that ES has version 8.x, I'd say this is quite old.

All the (working) "Hello, world!" examples on the Internet are using 5.x, or maybe 6.x.

- Why's Spring so far behind in the latest versions? (As a newbie in this area, I'd like to find out more).
- Are there alternatives to Spring Data for integrating Elasticseach with Spring?

Comment: As I understand the current situation, we are waiting for the 'upcoming' ver.4 of [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/4.0.x). Now I can recommend only such examples: [1](https://medium.com/@sourav.pati09/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-2b6106f2e2c), [2](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/03/elasticsearch-tutorial-beginners.html). By the way, I could use current SDES with ES v.6.5 (see my [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-mongo-elastic-demo))

Comment: @Cepr0: Thanks for these examples! I've had a look and I've been playing with one of them. Of course, it seems to only partially work, but I'll play around with it and try to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have been trapped by a bit outdated information in the Wiki. The question needs to be answered in terms of which ES client version a particular Spring Data Elasticsearch version supports. Which ES server version that in turn can talk to, depends on which client API within the driver you use.

Traditionally, Spring Data Elasticsearch has used the transport client which requires the server to run in the same major version that the client runs in. Current Spring Data ES (3.1.x, part of Spring Data release train Lovelace and used by Spring Boot 2.1) builds against ES client 6.2.2. You might be able to use newer client drivers but unfortunately, they often ship with breaking API changes even in minor versions which we (Spring Data ES and Spring Boot) cannot always adapt to. That said, this Spring Data ES version already ships with an implementation that allows you to use the high-level REST client with some manual setup.

The upcoming release train Moore will upgrade the client libraries to 6.8 and still stay on the transport client, i.e. working only with ES 6 servers OOTB. However, the same procedure as just described applies: you should be able to use 7.x client libraries and servers by switching to the high-level REST client in your Spring Boot application. A preview of the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RC3/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest).

I've [created a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-648) to update and unify the information. The [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/317) should make it into the upcoming GA release.

### Roadmap

After a few rearrangements in the maintainer structure, the project has seen quite a bit of momentum recently. There's a significant revamp of the module scheduled for the next Spring Data release train (presumably named Neumann at the time of writing). This is very likely to include the switch to the high-level REST client as default mode of operation from the Spring Boot auto-configuration point of view as well.

### Miscellaneous

Spring Data Elasticsearch is a Spring Data community module, i.e. it is maintained completely by volunteers that to a large degree spend their spare time helping to move the project forward. That means that it might lag a bit behind on support for the latest version of ES, features etc. We welcome every contribution and everyone willing to support the current maintainers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description of the status quo and your plans! I think that it would really help, if this sort of visibility is available somewhere in your project, such as perhaps the wiki on Github (perhaps in an `Announcements` section, or something similar). I think that something that is really important in your case is to have working "Hello, World!" applications for each of your releases, because that is the quickest way to get more developers on-boarded to your project. Obviously, this will also help with momentum! Once again, thanks for taking the time to clarify things!